# HighStocks series does not show line on Black Colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```
            let code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
            if (code === "000000" || code === "ac132") {
                code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
            }
            let colored = '#' + code;

            let dataset = {
                label: value.name,
                name: value.urls.name,
                color: colored,
                stickyTracking: true,
                showInNavigator: true,
                visible: true,
                data: value.values,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false,
                }

            };
```

[image]

And also the legend gets weird with black, covers the whole space and does not show other series properly, it only happens with black colors and its combinations.

I am using `Highstock JS v9.2.2 (2021-08-24)`

Here is the fiddle with one sample color code [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/srzj9oxu/1/)

Comment: Hi @Saad Mirza, Please reproduce the problem in some online code editor. As you can see in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/08hwxrn1/, the black color works as expected in Highstock.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/srzj9oxu/1/

here is the fiddle

Comment: Hi @Saad Mirza, Thanks for the example. The color: `#ac132` is not in a valid hex format. You should use six characters after hash: `#RRGGBB`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @ppotaczek the color code is **invalid hex format**.

New javascript code to create random colors

```
let code = "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
```